# Terminology: Flexible protrusion for a latch

Tags: mechanical-engineering, terminology

What is the name for a protrusion of material that's built to be flexible in order to act as a latching mechanism? These show up in all kinds of products, but one of the most recognizable is in a snap-fit buckle (below). Is there a name for this component?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Snap-fit" uses the same idea generally for any assembled part using elastic regime of the material. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap-fit